# create a array of random number then usestate hooks updates each and every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, setstate

Whenever i try to create a array of random number then usestate hooks updates each and every time. I also tried using bool values but still it re-render . Please help me how to solve this problem.

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  var isLoaded = false;
  function add() {
    let array = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=20;i++){
      array.push(Math.floor(Math.random*(10-6))+6);
    }
    if(!isLoaded){
      setArr(array);
      console.log('yes');
      isLoaded = true;
    }
  }
  add();
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setArr(array)` causes the component to be rendered again. When it is rendered, isLoaded is defined as false again and everything starts over because you call the function `add()` inside the component.

You can try this.

```
export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(() => 
    Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6)) + 6)
  );
  
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```